# CentOS Phonetic Keyboard Support

Tags: php, linux, centos, wkhtmltopdf, phonetics

[image]I am new to CentOS 7.5 and i am using wkhtmltopdf to convert my html code to pdf on local windows machine but when opened on CentOS(Server) after deploying the code the view is disrupted.So far what i found is that in my local system it's using phonetic keyboard to convert English language to my desired language and i can't find a proper version of phonetic for CentOS. Is there any way to overcome this problem.
Or should i use another operating if so which operating system supports this functionality except windows.

The converted file is this

Comment: Have you tried to install fonts like "msttcore-fonts-installer"?

Comment: Haven't tried that but i already know which font i am using it's jameel noori nastaleeq